# Failing to connect to MySQL-server through SSH and JDBC with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: mysql, jdbc, ssh, intellij-idea, xubuntu

My friend and I are working on a project where we try to SSH into a MySQL-database using JDBC, JSch and IntelliJ IDEA.
The problem is most likely not the connection attempt itself but, and this is my guess, som sort of environmental issue. I can SSH in through the terminal(yes, Xubuntu) without problems, but when i try to do it through code in IDEA it gives me

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'websp'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4074)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4006)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1694)
```

The thing that bothers us and supports the environment theory is that it works fine on another system.
I have installed IDEA with both 'sudo apt-get install IntelliJ...' and the downloadable file from JetBrains. I have imported the MySQL-connector(http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) into Project Structure>Modules>Dependencies.

I reinstalled IDEA to see if that was the issue but there is no change. Maybe i missed something?

Ideas?

Regards,
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

Concentrate on the connection string for jdbc.

Comment: The string is the same on the computer(my) it doesn't work on aswell as the one it does work on.

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort, dbUser, dbPass);

dbHost is 'localhost' and dbPort is '3306', (We use JSch's portforwarding).